# PHP array with foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to get two key values and add them both to a foreach. I can't seem to get it to work. Any help will be appreciated.

So I have an array that looks like this:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Code1] => M22
            [Code2] => M33
            [Code3] => S44
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Code1] => E22
            [Code2] => E33
            [Code3] => E44
        )
)
```

How can I search in the array and get the key and values for
Code2 & Code3 and add both of them to a foraeach?

I can get the Code3 by doing this. This works for the last array element using "array_pop" but can't figure out how to get Code2.

```
// Filter and get the Code3
$pcodes = array_map('array_pop', $this->dpparent);
foreach ($pcodes as $parent_code) {
    echo "\r\n". $parent_code;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain "get" a little more? Also, have you tried just a double `for` loop?

Comment: Get as in get the value of both keys 
code2 and code3

Comment: Have a look at [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column).

Comment: you can use foreach for every array and when find key return value and break the foreach .

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably a double `for` loop:

```php
foreach ($data as $subarray) {
    foreach ($subarray as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($key, ['Code2', 'Code3'], true)) {
            // Logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the keys, then you can use [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column) to extract the values:

```php
$code2values = array_column($data, 'Code2');
$code3values = array_column($data, 'Code3');
foreach ($code2values as $key => $code2) {
    $code3 = $code3values[$key];
    // do something with $code2 and $code3
    echo "code2: $code2, code3: $code3\n";
}
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
code2: M33, code3: S44
code2: E33, code3: E44
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/65vqG)